# How did the girl get in the car that Frank stole?

Tags: the-transporter

I'm watching "The Transporter", and I just noticed something that appears to be a plot hole.

After Frank delivers the "package", a girl, the receiver gives him a briefcase to transport, which turns out to be a bomb to kill Frank. Fortunately, Frank is not in his car when the bomb explodes. So, he goes back to the receiver's house for revenge. In the process, he steals a car to escape in. The girl is already in the car, but Frank didn't see her at first. But, the last time we see her, she is tied to an office chair wheeling herself into a hallway after the fighting begins. When Frank finds her in the car, she is still tied to the chair.

Everyone is distracted fighting Frank. She couldn't have opened the car door while tied up, let alone hefted the chair into the car, and closed the door behind her.

So, how did she get in the car? For that matter, how did she get into the garage?

Comment: It's not really a plot hole, as it doesn't really matter how she got into the car.  That's like saying it's a plot hole that 15 people couldn't kill Frank.  It happened because it was part of the script.  It's not a cerebral movie, it doesn't require strict logic to appreciate.